# Proper REST response if a requested field does not exist

Tags: rest, error-handling

If `fields` is not set, I return all possible car fields.  If an array is given for `fields`, I return only those fields.  For instance, the following query:

```
curl -X GET 'http://example.com/api/cars?fields=name&fields=color&fields=cost'
```

should return a list of all cars `[{"name":"Ford", "color":"blue", "cost":10000},...]`.

Now, another request, but this time also includes the cars horsepower.

```
curl -X GET 'http://example.com/api/cars?fields=name&fields=color&fields=cost&fields=hp'
```

But horsepower isn't supported by the application.  Should I:

- return only what is possible? ie `[{"name":"Ford", "color":"blue", "cost":10000},...]`
- return all requested fields but include `null` for unsupported fields ie `[{"name":"Ford", "color":"blue", "cost":10000, "hp":null},...]`
- Don't return any results, but return an error?
- Do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd return an HTTP error code `400 Bad request` along with an error JSON object such as `{"error":"Unknown field: 'horsepower'"}`, because you don't really know what the client wants to do. Perhaps they are requesting a non-existent field, or perhaps they've made a spelling mistake in one of the field.

If you silently ignore the error, it will be hard for the client to detect it. Better just return an error and let the client deal with it.

Comment: Thanks this.lau_.  I was going back and forth, and appreciate a simple answer with a good explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict guideline for handling above case. It all depends on your requirement.
A) If you want strict checking of the params then you can send **400 Bad Request** or

B) If don't you want strict checking of the params then return without hp field which happens in most cases.

C) You should not send with missing field as NULL as user can send any garbage and it will increase your processing time.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://example.com/api/cars?fields=name&fields=color&fields=cost&fields=hp
```

That identifies a resource....

> But horsepower isn't supported by the application.

Which is to say, there is no representation of `http://example.com/api/cars?fields=name&fields=color&fields=cost&fields=hp` available at this time.

Ergo: [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

The fact that your origin server happened to take the provided URI and map it to a handler is not germane.

Note that you don't need to leave the client in the dark

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

In this case, the representation could explain that `hp` is not supported, provide links to relevant tracking issues if you want to offer the client a chance to vote on it, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Voice of Unreason.  Let me mull it over.  In hindsight, I think (but am not sure) that I should have changed `?fields=name&fields=color&fields=cost&fields=hp` to `?fields[]=name&fields[]=color&fields[]=cost&fields[]=hp`